# Strange Warning When Compiling any Document

Tags: fonts, pdftex, warnings

I am getting the following warning even when compiling the most minimal of documents. Please help me understand this warning and how I might prevent it:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fontmap entry for `PTSans-Bold-tlf-ts1--base' already exists, duplicates ignored
```

The PDF output appears to be fine.

Comment: Do note: What you're getting is a warning message, not an error message. To help us determine the cause of the warning, please add a bit more background information: Has this message been cropping up ever since you installed TeXLive2011, or is it of more recent vintage? Did you do something in terms of installing fonts around the time that this warning message started cropping up?

Comment: First of all try running `sudo tlmgr generate updmap` and then `sudo updmap-sys`; does the warning persist? Have you run `updmap` sometimes (as opposed to `updmap-sys`)?

Comment: Mico: I only started getting the warning (yesterday) after running TeX Live Utility to update packages. Many packages were updated in the process. I did no font installation. egreg: I tried running those two command and there warning persists. I am not familiar with updmap.

Comment: @DJJerome Just run those two commands from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

This warning appears if you have insert a font twice inside your file `updmap.cfg`. Open the file and remove the font. After this run `updmap-sys`.